# How can I putting dynamically string into array using C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-programming, dir

J have below a code which display the name (this is char[]/string) of directories or files in given directory. I want to put this names dynamically to array. In print table1 displays correct the values(name of directories or files) which are iterate. But in other print table3 displays incorrect values. Could anybody help me with that? Is this problem with memory or something else?

```
char** do_ls( char dirname[] ){
DIR *dir_ptr;
struct dirent *direntp;
char **strArray;
int count=0;
strArray = (char**)malloc(1 * sizeof(char*));
strArray[0] = NULL;

if ( ( dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ) ) == NULL )
    fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
else {
    while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL ) {
        if(strchr(direntp->d_name, '.') == NULL) {

            strArray[count] = (char*)direntp->d_name;
            printf("\nTable1: %s \n", strArray[count]);
            count++;
            strArray = (char **)realloc(strArray, sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
            printf("\nCount: %d \n", count);

        }
    }
    strArray[count] = NULL;  /* Terminate the array */
printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[0]);
printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[1]);
printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[2]);
printf("\nTable4: %s \n", strArray[strlen(strArray)-1]);
printf("\nIndex: %d \n", strlen(strArray)-1);

    closedir(dir_ptr);
}



return strArray;
```

}

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example, including compileable code and a minimum set of file names that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer returned by `readdir()` points to a statically allocated structure, so you should not retain references to it after making subsequent calls, since every time you call `readdir()` again it'll just get overwritten.

You'll want to change:

```
strArray[count] = (char*)direntp->d_name;
```

to something like:

```
strArray[count] = strdup(direntp->d_name);
```

to make a copy of what it points to, rather than just trying to retain the pointer. Don't forget to call `free()` when you're done with it, since `strdup()` `malloc()`s the memory for you.

An alternative is to use `readdir_r()` which uses a caller-allocated structure, but for what you're doing this is likely not necessary, since you just want to store the name.

As always, don't cast the return from `malloc()` in C.

`strlen(strArray)` is wrong, since `strArray` is not a string, and `strlen()` only works for strings. You already maintain a `count` variable to keep track of the length of it, so just use that. This whole block:

```
printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[0]);
printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[1]);
printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[2]);
printf("\nTable4: %s \n", strArray[strlen(strArray)-1]);
```

is an obvious candidate for a loop, and can be replaced by:

```
for ( int s = 0; s < count; ++s ) {
    printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[s]);
}
```

or:

```
int s = 0;
while ( strArray[s] ) {
    printf("\nTable3: %s \n", strArray[s++]);    
}
```

since you set the last element to `NULL`.

Here's a fixed version:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

char ** do_ls(const char * const dirname) {
    DIR * dir_ptr;
    struct dirent * direntp;
    char ** strArray;
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( (strArray = malloc(sizeof(*strArray))) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ls1: couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strArray[0] = NULL;

    if ( (dir_ptr = opendir(dirname)) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        while ( (direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL ) {
            if ( strchr(direntp->d_name, '.' ) == NULL ) {
                strArray[count] = strdup(direntp->d_name);
                if ( strArray[count] == NULL ) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ls1: couldn't allocate memory");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                printf("Table1: %s\n", strArray[count++]);
                printf("Count: %zu\n\n", count);

                strArray = realloc(strArray, sizeof(*strArray) * (count + 1));
                if ( strArray == NULL ) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ls1: couldn't reallocate memory");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                strArray[count] = NULL;
            }
        }

        for ( size_t s = 0; s < count; ++s ) {
            printf("Table3: %s\n", strArray[s]);
        }
        printf("Number of elements: %zu\n\n", count);

        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }

    return strArray;
}

void free_ls_array(char ** strArray) {
    size_t s = 0;
    while ( strArray[s] ) {
        free(strArray[s++]);
    }
    free(strArray);
}

int main(void) {
    char ** strArray = do_ls("./");
    free_ls_array(strArray);
    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/dir_test$ ls
README      ls1         ls1.c       nothing.txt
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/dir_test$ ./ls1
Table1: ls1
Count: 1

Table1: README
Count: 2

Table3: ls1
Table3: README
Number of elements: 2

paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/dir_test$
```

Comment: What could I obtain size of array which are returned by function do_ls? When I call char ** strArray = (char **)do_ls("C:/PAP");

Comment: You can loop through it and count until you find the `NULL`. This is exactly what `free_ls_array()` does, except it doesn't actually count.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate method to how to grow a dynamically allocated array:

```
char **do_ls(
      const char *dirname
      ) 
   {
   DIR *dir_ptr = NULL;      /* A handle to iterate the specified directory. */
   int tmp;                  /* Used to iterate the array when printing it out. */

   char **strArray = NULL;   /* Array of string pointers for directory names. */
   int count=0;              /* Number of elements in the array */ 


   /* Open the specified directory. */
   dir_ptr = opendir(dirname);
   if(NULL == dir_ptr)
      {
      fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Scan directory entries. */
   while((direntp = readdir( dir_ptr )))
      {
      struct dirent *direntp;   /* Pointer to a directory entry. */
      char **tmp;               /* Used to safely grow the array. */

      /* Ignore current & parent directories, and all files with an extension. */
      if(strchr(direntp->d_name, '.'))
         continue;

      /* Increase the size of the array. */
     tmp=realloc(strArray, count+1 * sizeof(*strArray));
     if(NULL == tmp)
         {
         fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.\n");
         goto CLEANUP;
         }
      strArray = tmp;

      /* Store directory entry name into new array slot. */
      strArray[count] = strdup(direntp->d_name);
      count++;
      }

   /* Print array entries. */
   for(tmp=0; tmp < count; ++tmp)
      printf("Slot #%d: %s\n", tmp, strArray[tmp]);

   /* Add a last "termination" entry to the array. */
   tmp=realloc(strArray, count+1 * sizeof(*strArray));
   if(NULL == tmp)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
   strArray = tmp;
   strArray[count] = NULL; 

CLEANUP:

   if(dir_ptr)
      closedir(dir_ptr);

   return(strArray);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks evrybody for help.